# Sharepoint Online i Ofice 365 how to activate Top bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I have got a bar with Custom layout Theme in O365.

[image]

I need to put Search tab with search box like this:

[image]
How could I add a search bar to nav top bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, we can't add search bar to top bar.

As Trevor mentions, you need to add your user to Targeted Release.( Once this feature is released, these users will receive these updates at the first time.)

With this option, you and your users can be the first to see the latest updates and help shape the product by providing early feedback. You can choose to have individuals or the entire organization receive updates early.

More information:

[Set up the Standard or Targeted release options in Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your user to Targeted Release if you want to see it right now, but otherwise it is rolling out slowly to all tenants. This isn't a feature you put in place, it is one Microsoft is slowly deploying.

Comment: How can I do this ?